# After javascript jsonp callback call to my server I got 404

Tags: javascript, php, rest, api, jsonp

I need to build a cross domain script, I decided to use jsonp instead of CORS (I found it easier)

This is my JS client code:

```
function logResults(json){
  alert(json);
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.php",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "logResults"
});
```

This is my PHP code (new2.php)

```
<?php
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

    echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
?>
```

When I execute this I got
https://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.phpcallback=logResults&_=1498645452001
returning 404 (not found)

But when I call for: https://api.github.com/users/jeresig instead of https://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.php then everything is fine.

Note: when I enter https://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.php I see the returned json, as I should (so the code is working)

Do I miss something ? 
Maybe I miss something on my server side, some kind of header for example ?
Maybe there is something wrong with my json ?

I have already spent 2 days on this, and I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Does the following URL work? I've added a question mark:  https://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.php?callback=logResults&_=1498645452001

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error

Comment: It seems the problem is that https is not supported for that page. Can you try with http://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    "dataSrc": "Data",
    url: "https://my-server-domain.com/api_gt/test/new2.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
          logResults(res);
    }
});

function logResults(json){
    alert(json);
}
```